# model values are null when running ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following ActionResult in a controller called RoleController

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UsersForRole(RoleModel roleModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _roleService.AssignUsersToRole(roleModel.Users, roleModel);
    }
    return View(roleModel);
}
```

When I press save (from one of a few forms) on my view, the parameters of the model are all null.

The idea of this page there are 2 list boxes - model.Users (List of users assigned to a role), and model.UsersNotInRole (List of users not assigned to the selected role).

The view displays correctly, when I press Submit, I need to run _roleService.AssignUsersToRole() as shown in the controller.

**RoleModel.cs**

```
public class RoleModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public int LastUpdateBy { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public State State { get; set; }

    public virtual List<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual List<UserModel> UsersNotInRole { get; set; }

    public virtual List<RightModel> Rights { get; set; }

    public List<UserModel> SelectedUsersNotInRole { get; set; }
    public List<UserModel> SelectedUsers { get; set; }

    public RoleModel()
    {
        Users = new List<UserModel>();
        SelectedUsersNotInRole = new List<UserModel>();
        SelectedUsers = new List<UserModel>();
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of roleModel]

Any ideas why this is happening?

**View (Details.cshtml)**

```
@model Application.Core.Models.Roles.RoleModel
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_1_2">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UsersForRole", "Role", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)    
        <!-- BEGIN DUAL SELECT-->
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.UsersNotInRole, new SelectList(Model.UsersNotInRole), new {@style = "width: 75%; height: 300px;"})

        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Users, new SelectList(Model.Users), new {@style = "width: 75%; height: 300px;"})

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" />
    }
</div>
```

Comment: This is because you are not storing the selection of the list boxes therefore they are coming back as null.

Comment: what view are you trying to return? return View() will return the View associated with the actionresult, but since you're not sending anything with it, then it won't be populated. Use return View(model).

Comment: How do I store the selection in a listbox for MVC? Never used a List box with MVC before.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger in the browser or Fiddler to see what is actually being POSTed to the server? That might give you a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you will need two collections. To make things simple lets just focus on just one list box (same concept for the other one). If we take model.Users essentially you have the 'Users' property to populate your list box. However you will need another collection (for example SelectedUsers) to store your selection. Then in your view you will put

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedUsers , new SelectList(Model.Users), new {@style = "width: 75%; height: 300px;"})
```

In your post action result you will need to pass SelectedUsers (instead of Users) into _roleService.AssignUsersToRole

This [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZSP8tTAK1w) will help you

Comment: That does make sense and seems like the way forward. However if you see the screenshot above, the values in roleModel are null so I don't even get that far.

Answer (score 0):

Add to RoleModel:

```
public UsersNotInRoleType SelectedUsersNotInRole {get; set;}
public UsersType SelectedUsers {get; set;}
```

And replace in View:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedUsersNotInRole , new SelectList(Model.UsersNotInRole), new {@style = "width: 75%; height: 300px;"})

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedUsers , new SelectList(Model.Users), new {@style = "width: 75%; height: 300px;"})
```

Comment: If the parameter for the model in the [HttpPost] Action is the same name as a property in the model it'll be null and will fail validation saying the field was invalid. Do you have some rolemodel properties in model?

Comment: Validation does not fail, ViewState.IsValid is true and Yes, there are some and the controls are populated when loading the page.

Comment: Show your RoleModel class.

Comment: I guess i get it. Try: public List<int> SelectedUsersNotInRole { get; set; } and public List<int> SelectedUsers { get; set; }

Comment: ModelState is still valid, but the properties are still empty

Comment: SelectList should look like dict "Id" - "Name", property sould take List<IdType>, is UserModel Id field has int type?

Comment: Yes, UserModel has property Id which is of type Int

Comment: I dunno, remove [HttpPost] decorator